# It's possible to increase/decrease Frame's width/height from left to right/down to up?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, window-resize

Shortly, I couldn't do it, however I tried several ways but the *frame* still increases from start point and goes back to it.
That's happening with the height as it's *only* moving up to down not down to up.
Here I add a code that decreases the width:

```
for(int i = getWidth();i>0;i-=8){
    setSize(i,getHeight());
     try{
    Thread.sleep(sleep);
    }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Is there a way that the frame could have a mid point and the both sides goes to it?

Comment: This totally depends on the used layout managers.

Comment: So it's possible, but which layout manager have this ability?

Comment: The `Thread.sleep` on the EDT is not a good idea ... see the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial  for more info (summary: use the `javax.swing.Timer` instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you enlarge the frame, pack and re-center it on the display:

```
pack();
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Comment: Thanks it works, does it need a *pack()* method every time or only `setLocationRelativeTo` is needed, I tried `pack()` it won't show the increasing.

Comment: Good question: `pack()` is required to layout any components in the frame. Here's some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16316132/230513) using a timer instead of `sleep()`.