# Add Movable JPanel into JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have two classes `ClassFrame` and `ClassPanel`, now my `ClassPanel` extends `JPanel` and similarly by name `ClassJFrame` extends `JFrame`,

http://postimg.org/image/qpfgz8fpv/

### Conditions with `JFrame`

1. It already have other components like jinternalframe, jmenubar, toolbar, etc.
2. I have to add and show ClassPanel in between of jframe
3. ClassPanel always show above of other components

### Conditions with `JPanel`

1. I have add interfaces like Key, Mouse & MouseMotion Listeners,
2. So I can move the jpanel & set visibility false by making mousepress on top right specific area

Moreover my image can illustrate what is my requirement, but now I don't know how to
add panel with frame and move within it and show above of other components.

Kindly throw some light on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code about what have you tried so far.

Comment: A code would help us.

Comment: Two [complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16316132/230513)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use JLayeredPane to get the required output. Here is the tutorial about that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

Comment: yeah, that works good for my issue..... :D